# Update without matching values in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables without matching values
Tables 1

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 111 | AAA |
| 102 | 222 | BBB |

Table 2

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 103 | 333 | CCC |

I want to update table 2 below, that means for 103 I want 101 values from table 1

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 103 | 111 | AAA |

I used

```
update table 2 
set col2=(select col2 from table 1 where col1=101),
    col3=(select col3 from table 1 where col1=101) where col1=103.
```

Other than this there is any other query to use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` and specify the `Col1` value accordingly in the `WHERE` clause

```
UPDATE t2
SET    Col2 = t1.Col2,
       Col3 = t1.Col3
FROM   Table2 AS t2
       CROSS JOIN Table1 AS t1
WHERE  t2.Col1 = 103
AND    t1.Col1 = 101
```